# mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header

Tags: php, mail

**Tengo este problema , Tengo entendido que por una actualización de php ya no se permite n/ ni r/, lo quite de mi código pero no me llega el archivo que envió a mi correo, trato de enviar un archivo adjunto desde un formulario y solo me deja enviar todos los campos como , nombre, correo, teléfono pero no me deja enviar el archivo adjunto, el error que me envia es mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header** Mi código es el siguiente muchas gracias                                                                              .

```
<?php

if ($_POST){
$num = md5(time()); 
//MAIL BODY
$body = "
<html>
<head>
<title>Formulario | Trabaja con Nosotros</title>
</head>
<body style='background:#EEE;padding:30px;'>
<h2 style='color:#003B7A;'>Formulario | Trabaja con Nosotros</h2>";

$body .= "
<strong style='color:#003377;'>Nombres y Apellidos: </strong>
<span style='color:#666666;'>" . $_POST["name"] . "| 
</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;";  

$body .= "
<strong style='color:#003377;'>Email: </strong>
<span style='color:#666666;'>" . $_POST["email"] . " 
</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;";

$body .= "
<strong style='color:#003377;'>Tel&eacute;fono: </strong>
<span style='color:#666666;'>" . $_POST["telefono"] . "</span>";

$body .= "</body></html>";

$_name=$_FILES["filead"]["name"];
$_type=$_FILES["filead"]["type"];
$_size=$_FILES["filead"]["size"];
$_temp=$_FILES["filead"]["tmp_name"]; 

if( strcmp($_name, "") ) //FILES EXISTS
{ 
$fp = fopen($_temp, "rb");
$file = fread($fp, $_size);
$file = chunk_split(base64_encode($file)); 

// MULTI-HEADERS Content-Type: multipart/mixed and Boundary is mandatory.
$headers = "From: REFRIGERACION DIAZ <lopezericson233@gmail.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; "; 
$headers .= "boundary=".$num."\r\n";
$headers .= "--".$num."\n"; 

// HTML HEADERS 
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
$headers .= "".$body."\n";
$headers .= "--".$num."\n"; 

// FILES HEADERS 
$headers .= "Content-Type:application/octet-stream "; 
$headers .= "name=\"".$_name."\"r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; ";
$headers .= "filename=\"".$_name."\"\r\n\n";
$headers .= "".$file."\r\n";
$headers .= "--".$num."--"; 

}else { //FILES NO EXISTS

// HTML HEADERS
$headers = "From: GME \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n";
} 
// SEND MAIL
$success = mail("lopezericson233@gmail.com", "Formulario | Trabaja con 
nosotros" , $body, $headers);

if ($success){
  echo '<p class="feedback yay"><a href="index_trabaja.php" 
class="menu_arriba">Gracias por ponerse en contacto con nosotros, en breve 
estaremos revisando su C.V.</p>';
}
else{
  echo '<p class="feedback oops">Algo salio mal, por favor vuelva a 
intentarlo </p>';
}

}else {
?>
```

Comment: Que es `$num`? de donde se obtiene? puedes incluir donde se declara esto para completar el codigo. Ademas, hay algunas lineas que solo terminan en `\n` y no en `\r\n`

Comment: `mail()` [funciona bien] con Windows, por lo que el código no será portable. Recomiendo el uso de [phpmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), más eficiente, portable, te ahorra formatear headers o sintaxis compleja para adjuntar, etc. Bajas el zip y solo necesitas los archivos que están dentro de `src`. Hay mucha documentación al respecto por lo que ponerlo a punto será fácil.

Comment: Ya añadí  el código que implica el envió del formulario.